# Am I getting weapons damage rules right?

Tags: rotted-capes

Today I had a test round with start chars vs. mundane thugs. One of the thugs drawing a weapon and hitting by quite a margin, but only doing 3 damage on his damage roll (normal light pistol .22  so only 1d6 damage). What I'm wondering there is with thugs also having 14+14+14 = 42 stamina  a single gun (without eplxoding its dice quite a lot) would need over 7 turns to get a target to run out of stamina (as you can't get above their fortitude defense anyway).

Thus my question here is am I correct here or am I overlooking something there with handling a weapon (in this case a gun)?

Also am I seeing it correctly that light guns are weaker damagewise than melee weapons (due to the attribute dice also counting for them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **you add quickness** to ranged attacks just like you add might to melee, so there's no real difference there.

Second of all, while it's true it may take normal thugs 7 (or more) attacks to take down even a relatively squishy super, supers using firearms probably have both better weapons available than a standard light pistol and powers relevant to the weapon's use.

[As this review by 'Davenport' puts it:](https://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/16/16386.phtml)

> Damage is random based upon weapon type, with Might and Quickness adding to melee and ranged damage, respectively... I do wish that degree of success had more of an impact on damage, but the fact that the Martial Arts Advantage increases unarmed damage and the fact that Quickness adds to ranged damage helps in this regard.

Comment: Quickness you mean to the to hit roll and not to the damage roll right? (else I overlooked there something already).  But a good to hit roll has no effect on the damage roll as far as I'm aware in both cases right? 
Furthermore its not even the squishy supers there, but also for example one of the thugs taking a hostage....the thug would need to shoot 7 times in order to kill the hostage. (as not only supers hold out that much if I'm not overloking something as I meant)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you add quickness to damage, just like Might for melee weapons. That's the thing you overlooked, I think.

Comment: I wonder where that stands about quickness (never saw that part)

Comment: @dark can you maybe put in where its mentioned? (found it after your answer and my question in the part wehre the attributes are explained and quickness).